# How to get textview drawable resource id

Tags: android, android-layout, android-resources

I have an UI with some TextViews and I want to test if a textView has a certain drawable resource as background.  I'm using the following code, but the `tag` is always null.

```
Object tag = textView.getTag();
int backgroundId = R.drawable.bg_image_2;
if( tag != null && ((Integer)tag).intValue() == backgroundId) {
   //...do something...
}else{
   //...do something...
}
```

Which method returns the `R.drawable` background id number of an object? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Tag is a feature for developer to save some object with Widget, you have use setTag() to save an arbitary object with UI widget. If you didn't setTag(), then getTag() would return NULL.

Comment: Thank you! Now that I've understood what is the problem, it works like a charm. If you set your comment as an answer, I can accept it.

Comment: OK, I have move my comment to answer. Please accept it. I'm trying to raise my reputation.

Comment: @Evan Li :D. You post it as answer, if its correct you get upvoted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tag is a feature for developer to save some object with Widget, you have use setTag() to save an arbitary object with UI widget. If you didn't setTag(), then getTag() would return NULL.

Answer (score 1):

If the tag is null, it's because you didn't affect an Object to it with `setTag`